# Xamarin Button Style

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Hi I have two buttons in the Xamarin Form, which has to change it styles when one is clicked other is not.

I have to need as given in the image.
The one which selected should seen as ITEM2, and the other one should be ITEM1.

If i go and click on ITEM1 now it should take the style of ITEM2 and Item2 should take the style of ITEM1.
[image]

I have the basic Button code written using XAMARIN forms,as give below,

```
var Button1 = new Button
{
    Text = "ITEM1",
    Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(14, FontAttributes.Bold),
    BorderWidth = 1,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
};
Button1.Clicked += OnButton1Clicked;

var Button2 = new Button
{
    Text = "ITEM2",
    Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(14, FontAttributes.Bold),
    BorderWidth = 1,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
};
Button2.Clicked += OnButton2Clicked;

var tabHeader = new StackLayout
{
    HeightRequest = 48,
    //BackgroundColor = BrandingManager.LightGrey(),
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    Children = { Button1, Button2},
    Padding = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10)
};
```

Comment: You can have a function called in both click events with different input parameters to handle that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a method called `SelectButton(Button button, bool selected)` and then inside your OnButton1Clicked function have

```
SelectButton(Button1, true);
SelectButton(Button2, false);
```

and inside your OnButton2Clicked function have

```
SelectButton(Button1, false);
SelectButton(Button2, true);
```

The SelectButton method would set BackgroundColor accordingly:

```
public void SelectButton(Button button, bool selected) {
    if(selected) button.BackgroundColor = BrandingManager.Green();
    else button.BackgroundColor = BrandingManager.LightGrey();
}
```